# Solutions for “Stochastic Programming: Modeling Decision Problems Under Uncertainty".

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, stochastic-programming

I am currently reading *Stochastic Programming: Modeling Decision Problems Under Uncertainty* by Willem K. Klein Haneveld, Maarten H. van der Vlerk, and Ward Romeijnders (the 2020 Springer edition), and I am interested in solving the exercises.

However, there are no solutions to make sure I am on the right track.

Does anyone know if there is a solutions manual?